# How to generate uuid in solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, uuid

How to generate UUID in solaris 11?

In Solaris 10 i was using makeuuid command to generate.

I can not find it in solaris 11 while it exist as per oracle documents
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/makeuuid-1m.html

but I can't find it, also I can not find the container package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the very small Python program below. Would this help?

```
$ cat bin/uuidgen.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import uuid
print(uuid.uuid4())
$ uuidgen.py
c4f248e9-c398-4054-9208-6badd366f857
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that is exactly what I have done but we have done another shell script to wrap this file so we can use it in KCML programming

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `makeuuid` in all Solaris 11 packages:

```
# pkg search -flr makeuuid
INDEX      ACTION VALUE            PACKAGE
basename   file   usr/bin/makeuuid pkg:/system/management/product-registry@0.5.11-0.151.0.1
```

OK, what about that package?

```
# pkg info -r pkg:/system/management/product-registry
          Name: system/management/product-registry
       Summary: 
         State: Not installed (Obsolete)
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 0.5.11
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.171
Packaging Date: August  1, 2011 04:48:45 PM 
          Size: 5.45 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/system/management/product-registry@0.5.11,5.11-0.171:20110801T164845Z
```

Note that the package is obsolete. You can try force-installing it, but the Solaris 11 package system might remove it on your next update.

I'm not sure why it's obsolete, but the man page you linked is part of the [DCE/RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCE/RPC) OpenGroup [specification from 1997](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629399/).  The version string `0.5.11-0.151.0.1` seems to indicate an old OpenSolaris/Nevada package, likely from SNV version 151.

Note that `makeuuid` is not in the [Solaris 11.3 man pages section 1M](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54764/makehtml-id-8.html#scrolltoc).

If you really want that `makeuuid` binary, you should be able to download the package locally following this procedure:  https://serverfault.com/a/348265/283415  Once you have the package on your local system, you should be able to take it apart and pull out the `makeuuid` binary.  Note that grabbing the binary from the package won't install any dependencies, and the `makeuuid` binary from that old package may not work or it might work improperly on your later system.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will check your solution on our environment